# No value when deserialize XML document

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>235235263</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>dsgsgdsd</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>sdgsdg</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20060512</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>25</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>14</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>gsdgsgds</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>sgsdgs</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>325325</PostNr>
          <Postort>lalalal</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>235</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>2355325</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>35235</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>25</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>NEDERKALIX</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
</ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE>
```

And wanted to deserialize it but I'm not getting the value.

Here is the deserialize class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TESTMAPPNING2
{


        [XmlRoot("ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE")]
        public class Information
        {

            [XmlElement("Sekretessmarkering")]
            public string ProtectedIdentity
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            [XmlElement("PersonNr")]
            public string PersonalIdentityNumber
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            [XmlRoot("Personpost")]
            public class Personpost
            {
                [XmlRoot("PersonId")]
                public class PersonId
                {
                    [XmlElement("PersonNr")]
                    public string PersonalIdentityNumber
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }


                }
                [XmlElement("HanvisningsPersonNr")]
                public string ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber
                {
                    get;
                    set;
                }
                [XmlRoot("Namn")]
                public class Namn
                {

                    [XmlElement("Tilltalsnamnsmarkering")]
                    public string GivenNameNumber
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                    [XmlElement("Fornamn")]
                    public string FirstName
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                    [XmlElement("Efternamn")]
                    public string LastName
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                    [XmlElement("Aviseringsnamn")]
                    public string NotifyName
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                }
                [XmlRoot("Folkbokforing")]
                public class Folkbokforing
                {
                    [XmlElement("Folkbokforingsdatum")]
                    public string NotifyName
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                    [XmlElement("LanKod")]
                    public string NationalRegistrationCountyCode
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                    [XmlElement("KommunKod")]
                    public string NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                }
                [XmlRoot("Adresser")]
                public class Adresser
                {
                    [XmlRoot("Folkbokforingsadress")]
                    public class Folkbokforingsadress
                    {

                        [XmlElement("CareOf")]
                        public string NationalRegistrationCoAddress
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }

                        [XmlElement("Utdelningsadress1")]
                        public string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }

                        [XmlElement("Utdelningsadress2")]
                        public string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }

                        [XmlElement("PostNr")]
                        public string NationalRegistrationPostCode
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }

                        [XmlElement("Postort")]
                        public string NationalRegistrationCity
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }
                    }
                }
                [XmlRoot("Fodelse")]
                public class Fodelse
                {
                    [XmlRoot("HemortSverige")]
                    public class HemortSverige
                    {
                        [XmlElement("FodelselanKod")]
                        public string BirthCountyCode
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }

                        [XmlElement("Fodelseforsamling")]
                        public string BirthParish
                        {
                            get;
                            set;
                        }
                    }
                }
                [XmlRoot("Medborgarskap")]
                public class Medborgarskap
                {
                    [XmlElement("MedborgarskapslandKod")]
                    public string CitizenshipCode
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }

                    [XmlElement("Medborgarskapsdatum")]
                    public string CitizenshipDate
                    {
                        get;
                        set;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

And here is the Main class:

```
namespace TESTMAPPNING2
{
    public class Program
    {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }


        public static void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("navetout.xml");
            Information information = (Information)XmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
            Console.WriteLine("Information:");
            Console.WriteLine("Personnummer:" + information.PersonalIdentityNumber);
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

I'm trying to display the `PersonalIdentityNumber` just to try it out, but it's not getting it's value. All the console is printing is

> Information:
>
> Personnummer:

Why isn't it getting the value of the `PersonalIdentityNumber`?(`PersonNr`) in the XML.

**UPDATE 2**

My entire XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PersonNr>194903188953</PersonNr>
<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>194903188953</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Erik Lennart</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Enberg</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20060512</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>25</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>14</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>PÅLÄNGE 6:38</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>STORVÄGEN 65</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>95204</PostNr>
          <Postort>PÅLÄNG</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>250015520</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>2416233</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>22143838</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>25</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>NEDERKALIX</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <TilldelatPersonNrSamordningsNr>195405869370</TilldelatPersonNrSamordningsNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Fornamn styrkt="J">Eduardo Metran</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn styrkt="J">Garcia</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum xsi:nil="true" />
        <LanKod>14</LanKod>
        <KommunKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning xsi:nil="true" />
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser />
      <Fodelse>
        <OrtUtlandet>
          <FodelseortUtland styrkt="J">Sta Cruz Zambales</FodelseortUtland>
          <Fodelseland>FILIPPINERNA</Fodelseland>
        </OrtUtlandet>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod styrkt="J">PH</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>199103274545</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Fornamn>Sarah Dina Tomasdotter</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Själander</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20120123</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>01</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>80</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>SLALOMSVÄNGEN 3</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>STÖRTLOPPSVÄGEN 18 LGH 1102</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>12947</PostNr>
          <Postort>HÄGERSTEN</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>010114422</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>1463872</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>24865059</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>01</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>SPÅNGA</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>197111041617</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>10</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Kristian Fredrik</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Lahtinen</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20110524</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>04</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>84</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>HÖJDHOPPAREN 3</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>SÄBYGATAN 22 C LGH 1102</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>64434</PostNr>
          <Postort>TORSHÄLLA</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>040044272</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>1982769</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>22271866</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>04</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>TORSHÄLLA</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>FI</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>198208268220</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>10</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Ida Margareta</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Kruth</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20131101</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>23</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>80</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>FRITZHEM 17</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>TRÄDGÅRDSVÄGEN 7 A</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>83243</PostNr>
          <Postort>FRÖSÖN</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>230105629</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>2788100</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>22480810</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>23</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>RÄTAN</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>197707145590</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Bobby Sebastian Ari Roy</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Eklund</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20150915</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>14</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>89</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>JÄRTA 4</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>KUNGSGATAN 41 C LGH 1201</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>44131</PostNr>
          <Postort>ALINGSÅS</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>140856107</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>6170819</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>6251962</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>55</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>KULLINGS-SK</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>195907184930</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>12</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Nils-Arne</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Hellberg</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>19951002</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>14</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>35</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>MYREN 1:24</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>OLJESKÄR 19</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>45797</PostNr>
          <Postort>RESÖ</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>140255902</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>12613307</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>24298880</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>54</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>LUR</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>197002140098</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Fornamn>Robert Daniel</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Juhlin</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20131102</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>01</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>80</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>TRÄNGKÅREN 3</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>RÅLAMBSVÄGEN 19 LGH 1102</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>11259</PostNr>
          <Postort>STOCKHOLM</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>010129327</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>1447909</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>24809951</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>01</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>HUSBY-ÄRL.</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>195902134815</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Hans Peter</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Hultman</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20130809</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>13</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>82</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>SLÄRYD 1:19</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>SLÄRYD 122</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>31161</PostNr>
          <Postort>ULLARED</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>130150999</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>11291263</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>22077220</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>54</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>MÖLNDAL</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
  <FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
    <Sekretessmarkering xsi:nil="true" />
    <Personpost>
      <PersonId>
        <PersonNr>197306235057</PersonNr>
      </PersonId>
      <HanvisningsPersonNr xsi:nil="true" />
      <Namn>
        <Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>20</Tilltalsnamnsmarkering>
        <Fornamn>Carl Fredrik</Fornamn>
        <Mellannamn xsi:nil="true" />
        <Efternamn>Lundin</Efternamn>
        <Aviseringsnamn xsi:nil="true" />
      </Namn>
      <Folkbokforing>
        <Folkbokforingsdatum>20111201</Folkbokforingsdatum>
        <LanKod>12</LanKod>
        <KommunKod>82</KommunKod>
        <ForsamlingKod xsi:nil="true" />
        <Fastighetsbeteckning>OSCAR II 31</Fastighetsbeteckning>
        <FiktivtNr>0</FiktivtNr>
      </Folkbokforing>
      <Adresser>
        <Folkbokforingsadress>
          <CareOf xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress1 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Utdelningsadress2>FÖRENINGSGATAN 45</Utdelningsadress2>
          <PostNr>26136</PostNr>
          <Postort>LANDSKRONA</Postort>
        </Folkbokforingsadress>
        <Riksnycklar>
          <FastighetsId>120291075</FastighetsId>
          <AdressplatsId>1748543</AdressplatsId>
          <LagenhetsId>24233009</LagenhetsId>
        </Riksnycklar>
      </Adresser>
      <Fodelse>
        <HemortSverige>
          <FodelselanKod>54</FodelselanKod>
          <Fodelseforsamling>GREBBESTAD</Fodelseforsamling>
        </HemortSverige>
      </Fodelse>
      <Medborgarskap>
        <MedborgarskapslandKod>SE</MedborgarskapslandKod>
        <Medborgarskapsdatum>0</Medborgarskapsdatum>
      </Medborgarskap>
    </Personpost>
  </FolkbokforingspostTYPE>
</ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

Usings

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```

Code.... Copy and paste the following code into your Console application exactly as it is here.... and don't forget to create your xml.xml file using your xml, in the application *.exe folder....

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE> deserializedList = new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>();
            deserializedList = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>();

            var PersonalIdentityNumber = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("Personnummer: " + PersonalIdentityNumber);
        }// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>() where T : new()
    {
        // Create an instance of T
        T ReturnListOfT = CreateInstance<T>();


        // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
        using (FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream("xml.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
            // to serialize the data from the stream.
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            try
            {
                // Deserialize the hashtable from the file
                ReturnListOfT = (T)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
            }

        }
        // return the Deserialized data.
        return ReturnListOfT;
    }

    // function to create instance of T
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sekretessmarkering")]
public class Sekretessmarkering
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PersonId")]
public class PersonId
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonNr")]
    public string PersonNr { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HanvisningsPersonNr")]
public class HanvisningsPersonNr
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Mellannamn")]
public class Mellannamn
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Aviseringsnamn")]
public class Aviseringsnamn
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Namn")]
public class Namn
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tilltalsnamnsmarkering")]
    public string Tilltalsnamnsmarkering { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fornamn")]
    public string Fornamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Mellannamn")]
    public Mellannamn Mellannamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Efternamn")]
    public string Efternamn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Aviseringsnamn")]
    public Aviseringsnamn Aviseringsnamn { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ForsamlingKod")]
public class ForsamlingKod
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Folkbokforing")]
public class Folkbokforing
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsdatum")]
    public string Folkbokforingsdatum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LanKod")]
    public string LanKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "KommunKod")]
    public string KommunKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ForsamlingKod")]
    public ForsamlingKod ForsamlingKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fastighetsbeteckning")]
    public string Fastighetsbeteckning { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FiktivtNr")]
    public string FiktivtNr { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CareOf")]
public class CareOf
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress1")]
public class Utdelningsadress1
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string Nil { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsadress")]
public class Folkbokforingsadress
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CareOf")]
    public CareOf CareOf { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress1")]
    public Utdelningsadress1 Utdelningsadress1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Utdelningsadress2")]
    public string Utdelningsadress2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostNr")]
    public string PostNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Postort")]
    public string Postort { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Riksnycklar")]
public class Riksnycklar
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FastighetsId")]
    public string FastighetsId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AdressplatsId")]
    public string AdressplatsId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LagenhetsId")]
    public string LagenhetsId { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Adresser")]
public class Adresser
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforingsadress")]
    public Folkbokforingsadress Folkbokforingsadress { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Riksnycklar")]
    public Riksnycklar Riksnycklar { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HemortSverige")]
public class HemortSverige
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FodelselanKod")]
    public string FodelselanKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fodelseforsamling")]
    public string Fodelseforsamling { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fodelse")]
public class Fodelse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HemortSverige")]
    public HemortSverige HemortSverige { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Medborgarskap")]
public class Medborgarskap
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MedborgarskapslandKod")]
    public string MedborgarskapslandKod { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Medborgarskapsdatum")]
    public string Medborgarskapsdatum { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Personpost")]
public class Personpost
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonId")]
    public PersonId PersonId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HanvisningsPersonNr")]
    public HanvisningsPersonNr HanvisningsPersonNr { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Namn")]
    public Namn Namn { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folkbokforing")]
    public Folkbokforing Folkbokforing { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Adresser")]
    public Adresser Adresser { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fodelse")]
    public Fodelse Fodelse { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Medborgarskap")]
    public Medborgarskap Medborgarskap { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FolkbokforingspostTYPE")]
public class FolkbokforingspostTYPE
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sekretessmarkering")]
    public Sekretessmarkering Sekretessmarkering { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Personpost")]
    public Personpost Personpost { get; set; }
}
```

}

The code above loads your XML from a file called xml.xml in the application *.exe folder.... Check 'PersonalIdentityNumber' for your result....

////////////////

UPDATE 1

////////////////

For all the PersonalIdentityNumber in the new XML, replace ONLY the 'Main' function in your Console application with the code below....

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE> deserializedList = new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>();
            deserializedList = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>();

            var PersonalIdentityNumber = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr).ToList();
            foreach(var i in PersonalIdentityNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Personnummer: " + i);
            }
        }// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I tried: `Console.WriteLine(SerializerObj.PersonalIdentityNumber);` Is this correct?

Comment: Put a break-point in the code at the comment under the line that begins... 'var PersonalIdentityNumber =...' and then mouse-over 'PersonalIdentityNumber'

Comment: I did. Please check my updated question. It can't find it.

Comment: I have updated my answer... you need to copy\paste it exactly as it appears.... also use break-points + F10 and F11 keys to step though the code, its the only way your going to figure out how it works......

Comment: Thank you, it's working now! However, I would like it to loop through all values in the XML. How did you get that XML deserialized code? Can you check my "UPDATE 2" where I included the entire XML. I would like it to get all the values from the XML-tag (in this case `PersonalIdentityNumber`')

Comment: See my update 1 in the answer... Also your new XML does not seem to be well formatted.....

Answer (score 3):

Your XMLs root node is an `ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE`, which then contains a `FolkbokforingspostTYPE`.

However your deserialization class has no definition of `FolkbokforingspostTYPE`, only of the root `ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE`.

You can create a deserialization class automatically in Visual Studio using the special paste feature. Check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN link.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/jCc4w3pd) what my VS generated after I used your XML.

Check the usage [here](http://pastebin.com/hZ27sshi).

EDIT: I've updated both code samples. The initial code sample I provided worked fine for the XML you provided in the original question. The updated XML has a slightly different deserialization class which is nonetheless important. The new code samples work with the updated XML from your question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Whatever the reason, the definition doesn't match the XML.

Comment: @Shaamaan I tried, that but it doesn't work. I can't get any value from the class if I paste that into my deserialization class.

Comment: @Simon.S You're clearly doing something wrong. I can deserialize the object and get the value without issues. Check the code I added to PasteBin. It assumes the deserialization classes have been created as described in the MSDN link (I didn't change the names).

Comment: @Shaamaan I tried the code and get error 
`There is an error in XML document (9, 9).`

Comment: @Simon.S The reason it didn't work was because you didn't post the full XML. While I DID assume the XML would contain more than one node, the example you initially posted didn't, and my code parsed it without issues. I've updated the code samples using XML data from your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `FolkbokforingspostTYPE` is not mentioned in the code fragment, only `ArrayOfFolkbokforingspostTYPE`. The deserializer expects the member elements to be direct child elements of the latter.